# Integrate Angular to WordPress

Tags: wordpress, angular

Is there a way to integrate Angular 6 to existing wordpress page? For example page-reservation.php and here run angular project! 
Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a REST route on the WordPress side for that page to send the page content and call it from the Angular side using Angular HttpClient.

for more details about the WordPress REST API check
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

Angular HttpClient : 
https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Angular Elements](https://angular.io/guide/elements).

> Angular provides the createCustomElement() function for converting an Angular component, together with its dependencies, to a custom element.

With Angular Elements, you can create [Web Components](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements) (aka widgets) that can run *outside of Angular.*

---

*Note that there may be [limited/lacking support in some browsers](https://angular.io/guide/elements#browser-support-for-custom-elements).*